# Convert seconds since epoch to days since 0001-01-01 UTC in Python

Tags: python, datetime, time, utc, epoch

I have a time in Python that's represented as seconds since the unix epoch. However Matplotlib wants days since 0001-01-01 UTC (http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html).

How can I convert seconds since the unix epoch to days since 0001-01-01 UTC?

Comment: Is your python time a `datetime` type? If so, use the `date2num` helper function from the doc you linked to.

Comment: No, unfortunately it's a float that's equal to (fractional) seconds since the epoch. I'm hoping there's some clever way to do this without converting back and forth between datetime objects

Comment: UTC did not start till the 1960s.  Anything before that is certainly not universally defined.  But MATLAB may have _its_ understanding of UTC.

Comment: You just need to work out the number of days between 0001-01-01 and 1970-01-01 once.  Then add that to your number of days since 1970-01-01.  To work out the number of days, you can divide by the number of seconds per day (86400).  I'm pretty sure that the unix epoch functions always align with 86400 seconds per day (*ie* leap seconds are not counted).  This makes the math easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little more thorough reading of the documentation shows matplotlib.dates.epoch2num